# Append text to a group in a html document based on condition

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a large `html` doc. I have used `groups` to "group" the text and separate using `\n\n`. The entire text is within the `<font> </font>` tags of the doc.

Each group has 5 fields, `Serial#.........,Cust#...........,Customer Name...,BILL TO NO NAME.,DATE......`

I need to use the `Cust#...........` from each "group" and compare it against every other group in the list to look for a duplicate `Cust#...........`.

If a duplicate is found then I need to append `BILL TO NO NAME.` into each group with the duplicate `Cust#...........`

Sample html:

`Serial#......... 12345678974566321\nCust#........... 123456\nCustomer Name... Humpfrey Bear\nBILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 001166 - Some Company\nDATE...... 01/01/00\n\n'Serial#......... sgfdsfd546545645\nCust#........... 123456\nCustomer Name... Humpfrey Bear\nBILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 0165487 - Some Other Company\nDATE...... 01/01/00\n\n'Serial#......... Jgfdhdgfhgfdh4545\nCust#........... 88483\nCustomer Name... John Smith\nBILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 0146897 - Some Company\nDATE...... 01/01/00\n\n'Serial#......... JF2SJads5dsafdsaf\nCust#........... 015648\nCustomer Name... Eric Cantona\nBILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 8888154 - Man Utd\nDATE...... 01/01/00\n\n'Serial#......... JdsfrfdsgHG091797\nCust#........... 015648\nCustomer Name... Eric Cantona\nBILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 9876524 - Big Big Company\nDATE...... 01/01/00\n\n'`

The ouput I need is:
`Serial#......... 12345678974566321\nCust#........... 123456\nCustomer Name... Humpfrey Bear\nBILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 001166 - Some Company Bill To: 0165487 - Some Other Company\nDATE...... 01/01/00\n\n',Serial#......... JF2SJads5dsafdsaf\nCust#........... 015648\nCustomer Name... Eric Cantona\nBILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 8888154 - Man Utd Bill To: 9876524 - Big Big Company\nDATE...... 01/01/00\n\n'`

My output has omitted the duplciates based on Cust#......xxxxx, but I am just trying to show my expected result a little clearer. I can sort the duplicates out later.

A shortened version of what I have thus far the rest is insignificant.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib
import os



with open(r'.html', 'r') as f:
   html_string = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string, 'html.parser')

groups = soup.font.text.replace('Serial#', 'xxxSerial#').split('xxx')
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what the relationship is to your sample input and desired output?  The `BILL TO NO NAME` tag is in every entry in your sample input.  The desired output you have specified seems to simply be a single instance of the two duplicated entries, but there doesn't seem to be any appending of additional `BILL TO NO NAME` tags, and you also didn't say anything about omitting non-duplicates in your result. Some additional clarification would be useful.

Comment: There's also no HTML I can see in the input - it looks just like plain text.  I mean, plain text is a part of valid HTML, but I'm not sure why you'd need to use BeautifulSoup here, seems like any string manipulation method would be acceptable.  Is that right?

Comment: I have some code that will omit duplicates later, no need to worry about those. Correct I dont need beautiful soup I just started with it and kept going.. Open to any ideas

Comment: Ok, thank you.  What I'm still unsure about is this: you wrote "If a duplicate is found then I need to append BILL TO NO NAME."  But every entry in your sample input already has "BILL TO NO NAME".  And your output doesn't seem to any additional "BILL TO NO NAME" tags.  So if omitting dupes isn't the goal, and the text already has "BILL TO NO NAME", what are you trying to do - just identify which entries have duplicate `Cust#` values?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly like the expected output in your question, but it may get you close enough:

```
bills = """[your html above]"""
groups = bills.replace('Serial#','xxxSerial#').split('xxx')
cust_nums = []
ng= []
for group in groups[1:]:
    items = group.split('\n')
    cn = items[1].split('. ')[1]
    bill = items[3].split('. ')[1]
    if cn not in cust_nums:
        cust_nums.append(items[1].split('. ')[1])            
    else:
        items[3]+=' '+bill
        ng.append(items[:-2])
ng
```

Output:

```
[['Serial#......... sgfdsfd546545645',
  'Cust#........... 123456',
  'Customer Name... Humpfrey Bear',
  'BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 0165487 - Some Other Company Bill To: 0165487 - Some Other Company',
  'DATE...... 01/01/00'],
 ['Serial#......... JdsfrfdsgHG091797',
  'Cust#........... 015648',
  'Customer Name... Eric Cantona',
  'BILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 9876524 - Big Big Company Bill To: 9876524 - Big Big Company',
  'DATE...... 01/01/00']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to identify duplicate `Cust#` values, here's one approach:

```
import re

sep = "Serial#"

def get_cust_number(entry):
    """ Isolate the customer ID number. """
    pattern = re.compile("Cust#[^0-9]+(\d+)")
    return pattern.findall(entry)[0]

# return a list of dicts, each element has full entry and customer id
parsed = [{"full_entry": sep + x, "cust_id": get_cust_number(x)} 
          for x in data.split(sep) if x]

# example parsed element
{'full_entry': "Serial#......... 12345678974566321\nCust#........... 123456\nCustomer Name... Humpfrey Bear\nBILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 001166 - Some Company\nDATE...... 01/01/00\n\n'",
  'cust_id': '123456'}
```

Now use a `set` to look for duplicate `Cust#` and store the duplicate entries in `dupes`:

```
seen = set()
dupes = list()

# iterate over each entry, store :cust_id: values in :seen: set.
# if :cust_id: is already in :seen:, it is a dupe.  store it in :dupes:.
for entry in parsed:
    if entry['cust_id'] in seen:
        dupes.append(entry['full_entry'])
    else:
        seen.add(entry['cust_id'])
        
dupes
["Serial#......... sgfdsfd546545645\nCust#........... 123456\nCustomer Name... Humpfrey Bear\nBILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 0165487 - Some Other Company\nDATE...... 01/01/00\n\n'",
 "Serial#......... JdsfrfdsgHG091797\nCust#........... 015648\nCustomer Name... Eric Cantona\nBILL TO NO NAME. Bill To: 9876524 - Big Big Company\nDATE...... 01/01/00\n\n'"]
```

I don't understand why your output has the second "Humpfrey Bear" entry but the first "Eric Cantona" entry.  This answer generates a list of only duplicate outputs (meaning the first entry isn't there).